# CSS Gradient on DOM object, not background

Tags: css

I'd like to fade out a -Element on a webpage using CSS. I only find examples for background-color-gradients, is it possible to apply such an effect to the opacity of the object?

Attached you find an Image of what I mean. [image]

Comment: What you are searching for is CSS masks; but I don't know if that technique is production-ready already. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/ or https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ or https://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

Comment: thank you! I'll use that and tell my designer to create me a fallback design!

Answer (score 0):

Create auxiliary element over text and apply gradient to it's background.

Comment: works only when the background is a single color but unfortunately its on an image :-(